There is a $2$ ft wide street just inside a rectangular region and the area of the street is $1600$ sq ft. What is perimeter of the rectangular region
This is a problem from BDMO junior $(2004)$ math competition:

There is a $2$ ft wide street just inside a rectangular region and the
area of the street is $1600$ sq ft.
(a) find the perimeter of the rectangular region;
(b) beginning from one vertex of the rectangular
region young trees are planted at an interval of 1 m.  Similarly young
trees are also planted at an interval of 1 m along the perimeter of
the rectangular region  surounded by the road beginning from one
vertex. In total how many trees are planted?

I'm not sure how to solve part $(a)$ of the problem. The problem says there is a 2 feet wide street just inside a rectangular region but doesn't give any information about the distance of the margins of the street from the rectangular region. The following image shows how I visualize the problem.


I think you have the wrong interpretation of the street. My read of the question is that the street is all along the perimeter/border of the region.

@CalvinLin So the blue rectangle completely covers the black one?

I think there is a problem. Some informations are missing. You can consider that The Black rectangle is a square, and now, you can answer all questions. The street is JUST inside the square. The street is not the rectangle inside the blue line, it is the 'crown' between the blue line and the black line.

@user1380196 No. It might be helpful to think of it as a sidewalk 2 ft wide along the border, with a store in the center. The total area of the sidewalk is 1600. The area of the store is unknown. The sidewalk isn't a rectangular region, but an "annulus-like" region.

You are misinterpreting how the street looks; it should be a 2 foot wide ring around the inside of the black rectangular region as shown below. In this case, the street is not the inner rectangle, but the gray ring. 
Now you can write an equation for the area of this ring as $1600 = 4L + 4W - 16$ where $L$ and $W$ are the length and width, respectively, of the outside rectangular region. You can then solve for the perimeter and proceed from there.

Thanks, that makes a lot more sense.
